# Activity LaunchMode

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

This is the Activity tag i have in my Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity_B"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

What i want to accomplish is:

> Activity_A ---> Activity_B ---> Activity_C ---> Activity_B

When I go from Activity_B to Activity_C, i don't want to finish Activity_B.

But when I click a button in Activity_C, I want to launch Activity_B, which must be re-created (data changed because of some action in Activity_C) and the previous instance of Activity_B which is in the backstack must be finished.

`android:launchMode="singleTask"` which worked almost as required, but Activity_B is not being re-created.

`android:launchMode="singleTop"` re-creates Activity_B but doesn't remove its previous instance from the backstack

`android:launchMode="singleInstance"` this is working same as `singleTask`

Comment: How about using `startActivityForResult()` to start C, set result and handle it when returning from C to B? I suggest this way because most of the time changing the launch mode results in awful side effects...

Comment: Yeah. That's the 1st thing i thought of. But want to know if i can use LaunchMode. If that's the only solution, let me know, so that i can delete this post.

Comment: Have try Clear_TOP..try that once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*transforming comment into answer*

The workflow you describe is the perfect one for using `startActivityForResult()`. You should use that to call Activity-C from Activity-B and when the data was changed, set the result to `RESULT_OK` and if the user goes back, you can modify/update the Activity-B.

That is the way it is meant to be done.

Comment: Agreed. But `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` worked. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Triple check if you have any side effects. I would only use a different launch mode as a last resort...

Comment: Fine. Will go with your solution. Thanks a lot.